# Progressbars of parallel downloads in Python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, download, concurrent.futures, tqdm

I wrote a class with functions to download files from a website which requires a login. I also implemented a progressbar to the download function to keep track of the download progress using `tqdm`. Here is what I wrote:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import *
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed # for parallel downloads

class DownloadClass:

def __init__(self, url: str, usr: str, pwd: str):
    self.__file_url = url
    self.__usr = usr
    self.__pwd = pwd
    self.__req_skel = requests.Session()

def get_file_name(self):
    ... some stuff
    # returns the name of the targeted file using the request lib.

def get_file_size(self):
    ... some stuff
    # returns the file size of the targeted file using request lib

def download_file(self, dl_directory):
    _dl_dir = Path(dl_directory)
    _target_file = self.get_file_name() + '.zip'
    _dl_url =self.__file_url
    _file_size = self.get_file_size()

    with self.__req_skel.get(_dl_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self.__usr, self.__pwd), stream=True) as stream:
        if stream.status_code == requests.codes.ok and _dl_dir.exists():
            with open(Path(_dl_dir / _target_file), 'wb') as writer:
                pbar = tqdm(total=int(_file_size))
                for data in stream.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    writer.write(data)
                    pbar.update(len(data))
```

With this I can download files sequentially with e.g.:

```
urls=[...] # many file-urls which I want to download
user = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
dl_path = 'PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY'


# sequential download
for i in range(len(urls)):
    DownloadClass(urls[i], user, password).download_file(dl_path)
```

That works fine but I want to download files in parallel so I went with concurrent futures:

```
max_jobs = 3
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_jobs) as ex:
    futures = [ex.submit(DownloadClass(file_url, user, password).download_file, dl_path) for file_url in urls]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        res = future.result()
```

Atleast it executes 3 download jobs running parallel but the terminal output is a mess as every download progress of each file is printed to a new line (kind of overwritten). I rather want to have the updated progress of each download on the initial line like it is shown [here](https://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/post/progress-bars-with-rich/). I've found several examples which just combine the total length of parallel tasks and update the progress of the whole task but that's not what I want.